# I want to show records with multiple occurrences of the same value but only if a corresponding

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show records with multiple occurrences of the same value within a column but only if a corresponding column has different values against the original column.

For example:

```
Name    ID
NORTH   5762
NORTH   5762
EAST    7457
WEST    1234
WEST    1234
WEST    5678
```

I only need to see WEST as there is only 1 occurrence of EAST and although there are multiple occurrences of NORTH, they all share the same ID value.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you want WEST but not NORTH?  I do not understand.

Comment: Because NORTH has the same ID value for all records where it exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    TableName b
            WHERE   a.Name = b.name
            GROUP   BY NAME
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > 1 AND
                    COUNT(*) > 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cfa6/5)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ NAME ║  ID  ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ WEST ║ 1234 ║
║ WEST ║ 1234 ║
║ WEST ║ 5678 ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

or if you don't want to see all records,

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    TableName 
GROUP   BY NAME
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > 1 AND COUNT(*) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cfa6/7)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╗
║ NAME ║
╠══════╣
║ WEST ║
╚══════╝
```

Comment: If another "WEST,5678" is added to the table, I think the OP would want the query result to be 0 records.  Your second query would still return 1 "WEST" record.

Comment: @mbeckish - that is not how I read it -- more than one id for the ID column JW nailed it.

Comment: @JW웃 - Exactly.  When I run your second query, I get one record - "WEST".  The OP is not clear, but I think the desired result would be 0 records.

Comment: @mbeckish but they do not have the same `ID`. *4 records of WEST with two distinct ID* not *4 records of WEST with one distinct ID*.

Comment: @Hogan - I think your query got it right.  I wish the OP would come back and clarify the question.

Comment: @mbeckish - thanks -- I think JW is right.  Between the two of us one is right.  I wonder if the OP knows the difference.  Also, SO is funny, the OP probably thinks they should come back in a few hours and find no answers yet.  :D

Comment: @JW웃 - Your interpretation boils down to "Select each distinct Name N such that there is more than one distinct ID amongst the records with name N".  Hogan's interpretation is "Select each distinct Name N such that there is more than one distinct ID amongst the records with name N, AND there exists at least one record with a unique ID amongst the records with name N."  It remains to be seen which interpretation is correct.

Comment: I needed JW 's interpretation.Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to group by name and id and have only 1 result -- you do that like this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Table
WHERE Name IN
 (
    SELECT Name
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Name, ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
 ) 
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(NAME) > 1
```

Here is the fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7d16/1

Comment: FYI That's not my downvote, but just wanted to point out that I don't think that's what OP is looking for.

Comment: @AaronLS The first version did, I fixed it.